# Distributive law on right in ordinals

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

We know that distributive law on left holds for ordinals, i.e. for every ordinals $\alpha, \beta, and \gamma$ we have: $\alpha.(\beta+\gamma)=\alpha.\beta+ \alpha. \gamma$,
I know there is no law on right in general. My question is: if $\beta$ is a natural number and $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal, I heard that we have $(\alpha+\beta).\gamma= \alpha. \gamma$, How is its proof?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: `\cdot` will produce $\cdot$

Comment: What is the meaning of your comment?

Comment: Asaf is just telling you how to properly type multiplication. $\alpha \cdot \beta$, not $\alpha . \beta$.

Comment: Nitpick: the statement is not true when $\alpha=0$ and $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are non-zero.

Comment: We assume that $\alpha$ is non-zero. For example $(\omega^{3}+2).\omega5= \omega^{3}.\omega5$